# NameError: name 'domestic' in line 13 is not defined

Tags: python

Apologies for the long code as it's relevant whenever I call the main() function.
I am having trouble understanding how to solve this error as I thought I defined it inside the def function firstPackageUserChoice to be called back by main.

I had to take a chunk of the code away, but hopefully it still helps put some context to what I am doing.

Thanks in advance!

```
print( "Hello! We are going to determine the cost for shipping two packages" )

#Asking user for input on package weight
def userInput():
    package1 = print( int( input( "Please enter the weight of your first package: " ) ) )
    choice1 = input ( "Domestic or international for the first package: " )
    package2 = print ( int( input( "Please enter the weight of your second package: " ) ) )
    choice2 = input ( "Domestic or international for the second package: " )
    return package1, package2, choice1, choice2

#First package weight and shipping cost
def firstPackageUserChoice(package1, choice1):
    if choice1 == domestic:
        if package1 <= 2:
            domestic1 = 1.50
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${domestic1:,.2f}" )
    
        elif package1 > 2 and package1 <= 6:
            domestic1 = 3.00
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${domestic1:,.2f}" )
    
        elif package1 > 6 and package1 <= 10:
            domestic1 = 4.00
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${domestic1:,.2f}" )
   
        else: 
            package1 > 10
            domestic1 = 4.75
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${domestic1:,.2f}" )
    
    else: 
        choice1 = international
        if package1 <= 2:
            international1 = 5.00
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${international1:,.2f}" )
    
        elif package1 > 2 and package1 <= 6:
            International1 = 10.00
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${international1:,.2f}" )
    
        elif package1 > 6 and package1 <= 10:
            international1 = 15.00
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${international1:,.2f}" )
   
        else: 
            package1 > 10
            international1 = 25.00 
            print ( f"The cost of the first package is: ${international1:,.2f}" )
    return package1, choice1
```

Comment: You're using an undefined variable on line 13, didn't you mean to type `"domestic"` as in a string?

Comment: I'm sorry, that is meant to be written as "domestic1". I now see my error, but am getting an UnboundLocalError: local variable 'domestic1' referenced before assignment.

Edit: I will be figuring this out shortly. Thanks for pointing it out and David too for helping.

Comment: @JDL98, glad it helped, and welcome to SO. Please read this about the importance of voting and accepting helpful answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote. A vote is recorded with the arrow in the upper left of the answer, and an acceptance is recorded by clicking the checkmark in the upper left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either

1. define `domestic` in your definition
2. pass `domestic` into your function as you do with `package1`, `choice1` \
   or
3. make `domestic` a global variable 
   or
4. Is `domestic` a function and you simply forgot to include `()` ? 
   or
5. Is `domestic` a string ==> requiring `'domestic'`

That choice depends on a variety of factors, including whether `domestic` is changed by this definition.